# Multi Account Registration of AWS IoT Device certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have followed the links :
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/simplify-iot-device-registration-and-easily-move-devices-between-aws-accounts-with-aws-iot-core-multi-account-registration/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/x509-client-certs.html#multiple-account-cert
and I have registered a device or client certificate (signed by a different CA) with out registering CA.
When I tried connecting and publishing data to AWS IoT core with this device certificate ,it showing success on device side but the data is not reflecting at AWS IOT core.
I have set proper a)policy b)endpoint

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned whether the certificates you are using are recognized by AWS i.e. are they one click certificates generated from aws or they are signed by a different CA which AWS does not recognise.

In short:
You might need to register your certificate authority (CA) with AWS IoT if you are using client certificates signed by a CA that AWS IoT doesn't recognize.

If you want clients to automatically register their client certificates with AWS IoT when they first connect, the CA that signed the client certificates must be registered with AWS IoT. Otherwise, you don't need to register the CA certificate that signed the client certificates.

Reference:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/register-CA-cert.html

Comment: I have used client certificate s signed by a different CA which Aws can't recognize.

Comment: ok. When u say client does not give error does it mean a successful connection is created and only publish is not working. Is this understanding correct? Also can you enable cloudwatch to capture the publish event and check what error is showing.

Comment: I am getting this RuntimeError: 1038 (AWS_IO_FILE_VALIDATION_FAILURE): A file was read and the input did not match the expected value.

I have create A CA which is not registered on AWS and then used to create a client certificate , registered the client certificate .